# Shuffle huge table in sql3

Tags: python, sqlite, random-access

I am currently using the sqlite3 python package to access data in a table within a DB.
The table is quite huge -around 100GB- and I want to randomize its rows, since it contains training data for my NN, which needs to see the whole data several times.

Currently I am iterating through the table using the cursor, which fetches a part of the table, depending on my systems memory.

I know how to access the data randomly, but I do not know how to do it in a way, that I can access all the data in a table only once in an epoch. Thus, I am searching for a way to randomize the whole table, even though this might be computationally very expensive.

Is there an easy way to do it or do you have better suggestions? 
Thx!

Comment: maybe query just the primary key / rowid column, shuffle the result then query table in chunks based on randomised rowid/primary key values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is not SQLite specific, as I have not used it much, but more with SQL in general.

Two things there, either you care about reproducible results or not.
If you don't, you can do something like :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY random();
```

Otherwise when I want reproducible shuffle with SQL in general, I usually hash the concatenation of a value, lets say '1001' with a few of the values of a row.

```sql
SELECT MD5('1001' || my_column_1 || my_column_2) as r, my_column_1, my_column_2
FROM my_table
ORDER BY r;
```

Of course this is good only if the values in your columns change.

You can apply a limit like

```sql
SELECT MD5('1001' || my_key_1 || my_key_2) as r, my_key_1, my_key_2
FROM my_table
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 10000;
```

To get some batches and not the whole table.

Hope I have answered your question, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both options are great!

Comment: It is great if that is what you want, but just one thing, both answers will require a full scan of the table, which can be quite long. You may want to investigate on some more SQLite-dependant answers.

Comment: Both do work, but as you sad, it takes quite a long time. However, I have used the first approach to create a new table, which then can be read sequentially. One noteworthy thing is, that the shuffling command (not fetching) requires a lot of disk space, that is freed afterwards. I don’t know why though. Anyway, thanks again for helping me!